# Using Swift 5 to work with blender command function to render out frames

Tags: swift, macos, command, blender

I have been trying to get this application to work for a while now but I can´t seem to get it to work.

I know I had to setup my sandbox when using Xcode-Swift. This is setup. I can get the application command line to work. When I am in the terminal works just fine.

But in the swift app I get this error.

> Log:"Command output:Error: Cannot read file '/Users/andyhaz/Library/Containers/com.gamerocketstudio.render-shop/Data/-b /Users/andyhaz/Documents/testBoxA.blend -o /Users/andyhaz/Documents/ -f 1': No such file or directory"

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
 
    
    let blenderPath:String = "/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/MacOS/Blender"
    print(blenderPath)
    
  let argsPath:String = "-b /Users/andyhaz/Documents/testBoxA.blend -o /Users/andyhaz/Documents/ -f 1"
  //let argsPath:String = "--help"
    
    let commandOutput = executeCommand(command:blenderPath, args:[argsPath])//"/bin/echo"
    print("CO:\(commandOutput)\n")
    print("Command output:\(commandOutput)")
    
}
```

I will not read the blender file testboxA.blender and will to render out the file image. In the terminal it will work just fine. Just not in the swift code.

Here is the terminal command:

```
blender -b yourfile.blend -o OutPath -f 1
```

The test

```
/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/MacOS/Blender -b /Users/andyhaz/Documents/testBoxA.blend -o /Users/andyhaz/Documents/ -f 1
```

work just fine.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I will not read the blender file testboxA.blender and will to render out the file image. In the terminal it will work just fine. Just not in the swift code.

Comment: here is the terminal command blender -b yourfile.blend -o OutPath -f 1

Comment: the test  /Applications/Blender.app/Contents/MacOS/Blender -b /Users/andyhaz/Documents/testBoxA.blend -o /Users/andyhaz/Documents/ -f 1
work just fine

Comment: Is `executeCommand` expecting one string with all arguments or an array with arguments like `["-b", "/Users/andyhaz/Documents/testBoxA.blend", "-o", "/Users/andyhaz/Documents/", "-f", "1"]`?

Comment: is's one string, no array

Comment: would it be better to use an array? then join it to create a string?

Comment: Why is [argsPath] an array if it's one string? Is `executeCommand` expecting one string or is it expecting an array like `NSTask` and `Process`? Post the code of `executeCommand` please.

Comment: let commandOutput = executeCommand(command:blenderPath, args:argsPath)//"/bin/echo"
you will get an error: Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type '[String]'

Comment: I update the code for an array but still get error massage         let commandOutput = executeCommand(command:blenderPath, args:[argFile,argSave,argFrame])//"/bin/echo"
      //print("CO:\(commandOutput)\n")
        print("Command output:\(commandOutput)")

Comment: Do you have a link to the `executeCommand` documentation?